# Parse a multidimensional array from .ini file

Tags: php, ini

I am wondering if there is anyway to (in an .ini file) implement something that when parsed by the `parse_ini_file()` (in php) will create a multidimensional array instead of just an associative array?

I've been searching but have came up empty, so I was wondering if anyone over here might have an idea on whether something like this is allowed or not.

Example:

file.ini (semi-sudo-code):

```
input = input1 = ('Hello world this is test #1')
input = input2 = ('Hello world this is test #2')
```

code.php:

```
$array = parse_ini_file("file.ini", true);
print_r($array);
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [input] => Array
        (
            [input1] => Hello world this is test #1
            [input2] => Hello world this is test #2
        )

)
```

Comment: Why not just use JSON instead?

Comment: @ADyson Yea, that is what I am doing currently, but I like the simplicity of a `.ini` file so want to see  if there is a way to get a multidimensional array while using it.

Comment: You find JSON complicated then? But you're trying to work with a more complicated set of data, so a storage format which can trivially accommodate that makes more sense. IMHO the ini format in your answer below is harder to read (for humans I mean). But glad you found yourself an answer.

Comment: Well that's why im using this for a small simple set of data so it can easily be edited, added to, and/or deleted. JSON is more strict on format unlike ini, making that process a bit more tedious for me to go into and edit if need be. For larger data sets of course JSON is the better solution, just not for the 3 to 4 variables that will be changed once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I found my own answer after figuring out a better way to word my question.

.ini Files can have sections that are enclosed in brackets `[ ]` for example:

```
[input]
  input1 = ('Hello world this is test #1');
  input2 = ('Hello world this is test #2');
```

This is exactly what I was looking for as the sections (when parsed) turn it into a multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [input] => Array
        (
            [input1] => Hello world this is test #1
            [input2] => Hello world this is test #2
        )

)
```

Definitely should've waited a bit longer and researched a bit more before posting this question, but I'll leave it up for others who may have the same problem as I initially did.